# How can I parse the site after the site loaded the javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jsoup

I want to display the webpage HTML after it loads the javascript so that I can get an accurate representation of the tables.

I have tried using other jar but this one is the only one that seem to work for me because the rest looks outdated.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Download bestanden\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("headless");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
    System.out.println(doc.select("ul.submenu.hidden li a").text());
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("Completed");
```

If I search for lmenu_17 I expect more results than Superlinga by Albania as a href, I expect First Division Albanian cup and Super Cup to be displayed as well like they do in the inspector. 
Thank you in advance any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.flashscore.com/");

        //works after the page is fully loaded.
        //goes to a bottom line.

        string href = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='lmenu_17']/ul/li[1]/a").GetAttribute("href"); // albanian link
        //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(href);

        foreach (var element in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='lc']/div[6]/ul/li/a")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("href"));
        }

        driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='lc']/div[6]/ul/li[12]/a").Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        foreach (var element in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='lc']/div[9]/ul/li/a")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("href"));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

you don't need to get the page source.

[picture of working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMRbo.png)
I don't know if it'll help. Happy if I could help.

Comment: Thank you so much! All thanks to you I solved it, the problem wasn't that the page HTML changed after the JavaScript loaded but it changed after you clicked an element, so I made it click the element I want and after that parse the HTML to Jsoup so that I can still use Jsoup syntax. Here is the code if anyone is interested.

Comment: <code>System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Download 
    bestanden\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.flashscore.com/");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lmenu_17']/a"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.}
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());</code>